# Redirection from main domain to add-on domain

Tags: domains, redirects, 301-redirect, add-on-domain

I want to redirect the main domain to an add-on domain using 301: Is it important that the main domain will be the one pointing to the add-on domain? Does this have any negative effect from a technical or SEO point of view?

Both are hosted on the same hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any reprecussions. As of 2016 there is no longer any issues for any type of 300 redirect. You will not lose page rank.

Check out this article for some more information. 
[Article about SEO changes.](https://moz.com/blog/301-redirection-rules-for-seo)